# How to geocode destination point?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I am trying to navigation application on Mapbox with Unity. I can take the location of the user but i could not able to take destination point from the user. I want to take as text. If i can able to take destination point, i can plot the route easily.

I tried the reload map, but it is not useful. Also, i tried the forward geocode user input file, but i could not make it.

```
    namespace Mapbox.Examples
    {
        using Mapbox.Unity;
        using UnityEngine;
        using UnityEngine.UI;
        using System;
        using Mapbox.Geocoding;
        using Mapbox.Utils;

        [RequireComponent(typeof(InputField))]
        public class ForwardGeocodeUserInput : MonoBehaviour
        {
            InputField _inputField;

            ForwardGeocodeResource _resource;

            Vector2d _coordinate;
            public Vector2d Coordinate
            {
                get
                {
                    return _coordinate;
                }
            }

            bool _hasResponse;
            public bool HasResponse
            {
                get
                {
                    return _hasResponse;
                }
            }

            public ForwardGeocodeResponse Response { get; private set; }

            //public event Action<> OnGeocoderResponse = delegate { };
            public event Action<ForwardGeocodeResponse> OnGeocoderResponse = delegate { };

            void Awake()
            {
                _inputField = GetComponent<InputField>();
                _inputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(HandleUserInput);
                _resource = new ForwardGeocodeResource("");
            }

            void HandleUserInput(string searchString)
            {
                _hasResponse = false;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    _resource.Query = searchString;
                    MapboxAccess.Instance.Geocoder.Geocode(_resource, HandleGeocoderResponse);
                }
            }

            void HandleGeocoderResponse(ForwardGeocodeResponse res)
            {
                _hasResponse = true;
                if (null == res)
                {
                    _inputField.text = "no geocode response";
                }
                else if (null != res.Features && res.Features.Count > 0)
                {
                    var center = res.Features[0].Center;
                    //_inputField.text = string.Format("{0},{1}", center.x, center.y);
                    _coordinate = res.Features[0].Center;
                }
                Response = res;
                OnGeocoderResponse(res);
            }
        }
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get destination point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004248/how-to-get-destination-point)